# What does o'377' mean in Fortran 77?

Tags: fortran

What does it mean o'377' in Fortran 77? When I tried to print it outputs 255.

```
print*,"result", o'377'
```

which returns

```
result 255
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. You should write your actual question in the question body, not just into the title. Make the title short and concise.

Comment: In Fortran 77 it means nothing. I'm not sure when this came into the language, but it is at least Fortran 90.

Comment: It is also invalid code. boz-literals cannot appear in print-statements.

Answer (score 3):

It's an octal (base 8) representation. 377 octal is 255 decimal or FF hex.

Answer (score 1):

This is what they call a *boz-literal-constant*:

> A binary, octal, or hexadecimal constant (*boz-literal-constant*) is a sequence of digits that represents an ordered sequence of bits. Such a constant has **no type**.
>
> R764 *boz-literal-constant* is *binary-constant*, *octal-constant* or *hex-constant*
>   R765 *binary-constant* is `B ’ digit [ digit ] ... ’` or `B " digit [ digit ] ... "` 
>   C7107 (R765) `digit` shall have one of the values `0` or `1`.
>   R766 *octal-constant* is `O ’ digit [ digit ] ... ’` or `O " digit [ digit ] ... "` 
>   C7108 (R766) *digit* shall have one of the values `0` through `7`.
>   R767 *hex-constant* is `Z ’ hex-digit [ hex-digit ] ... ’` or `Z " hex-digit [ hex-digit ] ... "` 
>   R768 hex-digit is *digit* or `A` through `F`
>
> C7109 (R764) A *boz-literal-constant* shall appear **only** as a *data-stmt-constant* in a DATA statement, or where explicitly allowed in 16.9 as an actual argument of an intrinsic procedure.
>
> **<sub>source: [Fortran 2018 Standard Section 7.7](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)</sub>**

As is seen from the Standard, a boz-literal constant has no type and can only appear in data-statements or some implicit functions. This implies that the notation:

```
print*,"result", o'377'
```

is invalid code since the octal representation has no type. The correct code would have read:

```
print *, "result", INT(o'377')
```

However, in Fortran 90 this would also have been invalid as one could only use boz-literal constants in DATA-statements. The only valid way would have been:

```
INTEGER :: constant
DATA constant /o'377'/
print *, "result", constant
```

---

**note:** Some compilers allow the usage of boz-literal-constants outside of the DATA statement. Solaris-studio converts them to the type required by the context. Other compilers might have different opions on that.